# How metadata in java helps to prevent segmentation fault?

Tags: java, c, metadata

C-code snippet :--

```
int ary[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)

 {
 dosomething();
 }
```

java-code snippet :-

```
 int [] ary = new int (100); // int ary [] …

 for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) 

 do_something();
```

In C code,it may lead to segmentation fault,but in Java code due to length metadata,it will

not happen.can somebody explain it in detail?

Comment: Arrays are objects in Java unlike in C

Comment: What is there to explain? You can still go beyond the bounds of the array in Java, if you use a literal upper bound in the loop as in the C example. You will get an exception in Java if you do this, in C you have *undefined behavior* if you go out of bounds and it *might* lead to a crash.

Comment: Metadata? I guess you mean classes (as in OOP).

Comment: Also, as for proper arrays in C (like in your example) you can get the exact number of entries: `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ary) / sizeof(ary[0]); ++i)`. Of course, as soon as it has decayed to a pointer it's no longer possible.

Comment: Java keeps track of the array size and will throw an out of bounds exeption when the index exceedes the limit.  C could care less about array size.  It is just memory address, and you need to ensure your code stays in bounds.

Comment: In C, array is a pointer to the memory address, and with index you access that memory. When your index accesses a memory which is outside of the array you may try to access memory which does not belong to your process. In such situation kernel will kill you with segmentation fault. IOW, segmentation fault tells you that you are trying to access memory outside of your process. In some situation you will get some rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM does various safety checks in runtime, including bounds checking. So you won't get a segfault from trying to access a location outside of the array, but you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It's among the nice features of having a (semi-)interpreted language.

Answer (score 1):

C code for accessing arrays assumes that the programmer knows what he's doing, so it never checks array indexes for you. If you want your array index to be checked, you must do it yourself. If your do not check the index, and it turns out to be outside the allocated region of memory for the array, it's undefined behavior, which may case segmentation faults. Unfortunately, undefined behavior does not always cause a crash, so an error may go unnoticed for a long time.

In Java, on the other hand, the compiler does not trust you to do the right thing. It stores array's length along with the array, and checks your index to be non-negative before accessing the array.

Note that this prevents undefined behavior, but it does not necessarily prevent a crash: if your program tries to access an index outside the valid range, JVM would throw a runtime exception, which will bring down your program, unless you catch the exception. The advantage of this approach is that your program fails fast, before the incorrect read or write could do any harm.

Comment: Does the compiler really store the array length in the bytecode? I would have thought it is just runtime data.

Comment: @Puce The actual data is stored along with the array for access at runtime, not in the bytecode. It is metadata only in the sense that it's not data, not in the sense that it's part of bytecode.

Comment: So maybe you could rewrite "the compiler does not trust you to do the right thing. It stores array's length along with the array,"?

Comment: @Puce Why rewrite? The array length is indeed stored together with the array, so what's the problem? If you would like to suggest a better wording for this, please feel free to edit - I always appreciate good edits!

Comment: I think I misunderstood it. The actual bytcode instruction to create an array seems to always require a length, unlike the Java syntax where it can be implicit. Correct? Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Puce Correct - even in cases when the array length is determined from the initializer's length, the compiler does the counting, and sets up the length.

Answer (score 1):

In detail the JVM does simply add "magic code" to the final bytecode assembly during runtime that includes bounds checking [as specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.aaload) in the form of:

```
if (i < 0 || i >= length) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

This of course has to be done for each access and will with a simple implementation slow down array access a lot. However there are many attempts to circumvent that with more sophisticated ideas like [this](http://ssw.jku.at/Research/Papers/Wuerthinger07/Wuerthinger07.pdf) or [this](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~dkl/research/papers/ics.pdf). Google can help you to find more.

Some JVMs might already use more sophisticated methods, while others do simply add the check as above to every instruction that accesses an array index during the runtime execution/compilation of code.

Comment: Is this really added to the bytcode? I thought this is just what the JVM does when accessing arrays... (JVM spec)

Comment: That depends on the implementation of the JVM. Something that runs under Windows x64 might do something entirely different than something that runs on your Raspberry Pi. But maybe I should clarify when this is added, which is during runtime and not during compilation.

Comment: What dependes on the implementation of the JVM? The bytecode? This is generated by the compiler not the JVM. Isn't the array check part of the JVM specification and every implementation has to check/ assure it one way or the other?

Comment: Whether or not this is added and in which form is dependent on the JVM. The bytecode is generated by the compiler and the JVM has no influence on that till it is actually executed during runtime. But the JVM specification defines that accessing an array has to throw an exception when using an invalid index.

Comment: Now with 20% more links. ;)

Comment: My point is that you wrote the check is "add "magic code" to the final bytecode assembly", which is probably not true for most implementations. Thy bytecode is probably untouched and just an internal JVM check method gets called (native code). At least that yould be my guess.

Comment: The emphasis is on _assembly_, which is for a JIT usually an actual machine code, that will then include those checks.